# In Bridge, Is it Sometimes Good to Lead an Opponent's Suit on Defense?

Tags: bridge, openings

I was "West," that is, the opening leader. My left and right hand opponents had alternated diamond and spade bids, neither supporting the other, suggesting something like 6-1 misfits in both suits (which actually turned out to be the case), and South bought the contract at four spades.

I held something like:

♠xx
♥Qxx
♦JTxx
♣Qxxx

led a low heart (the unbid major). This gave the opponents a free finesse, and the contract was (barely) made.

I had also given consideration to a diamond lead from the JT sequence. Since South had only one diamond, he couldn't finesse out the T or capture it when guarded by xx, after capturing the J with a higher honor. With honors in all three plain suits, I even thought of (and rejected) the "safe" lead of a low trump. The last alternative was to lead the fourth club, which at least left TWO guards for the queen.

Did I make a bad lead? Should I have led either a diamond or spade, instead, even though both had been bid by the opponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the opponents were not overbidding, your lead was perfectly fine. (though with lead problems, you ought to give the complete auction, as that matters a lot).

Elaborating on my comment to thesun...'s answer:

Usually when dummy bids and rebids a suit and you have a weak stopper like JTxx, there is real danger of that suit being set up or losers from declarer's hand immediately going away (for instance AKQxxx opposite void and declarer throws away heart/club losers).

Such auctions (where dummy shows a real suit) usually call for an attacking lead and a trump lead is quite bad in that respect. There is also the distinct possibility the dummy is void in trumps and you are giving declarer a finesse he could not take, if you lead a trump.

A diamond lead is similarly bad as you are just giving declarer the option to throw away his losers immediately.

So the only reasonable choices (IMO) on this hand are either a heart or a club and either is ok, as to beat the contract you would probably need tricks from both suits.

btw: Try not to make conclusions from just one hand. Even a 90% odds on play has to fail 10% of the time.

Comment: The auction was 1d, 1s, 2d, 2s, 3d, 3s, 4d, 4s. That's what I meant by "alternating diamond and spade bids, neither bidder supporting the other." Opponents had 29-30 points to compensate for only 7 spades, just made it.

Comment: @Tom: Assume they are playing "standard american", your opponents are either crazy or beginners. Against such auctions, there might be no logical leads! I would probably lead a club though, as that might be safer than a heart. (I still would be reluctant to lead a spade or diamond).

Comment: @Tom: btw, I am curious. What were the opponents hands?

Answer (score 1):

I certainly sometimes lead opponent's trumps when I can see literally nothing else attractive to do.  As a way of getting the lie of the land it's pretty safe.  And it's not like you were planning on making any quick tricks with those spades in your hand, right?

It seems especially attractive here.  With a horrible 6-1 spade fit it's not like drawing trumps is likely to be opponents' first priority.  Knocking out dummy's sole trump may limit the opponent's options and eliminates the possibility of the "free finesse" that you mentioned.  In what is otherwise a vacuum of information about which unbid suit to lead, I'd probably have gone for it...

Comment: Knocking out entries from dummy is certainly sometimes useful. But not always ;-)

Comment: -1: Usually when dummy bids and rebids a suit and you have a weak stopper like JTxx, there is real danger of that suit being set up or losers from declarer's hand immediately going away. Such auctions call for an attacking lead and a trump lead is quite bad in that respect. There is also the distinct possibility the dummy is void in trumps and you are giving declarer a finesse he could not take.

Comment: Mm, yes, I suppose a void opposite a void is quite likely in the case of the (unusual) bidding sequence that's now been outlined by Tom, where they deny each other's suit 3-4 times each.  I'd maintain that it's not always bad to lead the opponents' suit on defence, to answer the question in the title, though perhaps it was a rash thing to propose on this particular deal...

Comment: Look for instance at this table of suggestions for how to lead: http://www.bridgehands.com/O/Opening_Leads.htm.  It suggests leading a (non-singleton) trump when "opponents have a misfit or a mediocre fit".  That's exactly what's going on here, no?

Comment: @thesun: You are talking about 5A?  Why ignore 4A? I would rather trust Eddie Kantar any day over some random website. See here: http://books.google.com/books?id=r0dtP5H3NJYC&pg=PA34. To give the bridgehands site the benefit of doubt, the 5A is probably talking about the case when declarer has shown two suits and dummy has given preference to the second suit (and so is likely to be short in the first suit). In general when dummy is expected to be short in trumps, a trump lead is quite bad.

Comment: btw, there will usually be multiple factors which might suggest contradictory leads. So just stating one factor is not enough, you have to weigh them appropriately.

Comment: That's the beauty of bridge, isn't it?  That there are different schools of thought.  Eddie Kantar's school is an excellent one but perhaps he doesn't often play against opponents who each angrily insist on their suit four times each.  Who knows?  I like leading trumps in such situations, you don't, you've downvoted my answer, all is well in the world.  I'm just saying that (while I'm no world-class Bridge expert, just a casual player), I'm not making completely random assertions, some self-appointed experts don't forbid leading trumps in all situations!

Comment: @thesun: It is not about likes/dislikes, nor is this a borderline/difficult lead problem where you need to invoke 'schools of thought', where there might differences of opinion between experts. A trump lead really is quite bad, as explained here and in Eddie Kantar's book. Other than a link to some random website (where 5A is misguided/incomplete, in fact), I really don't see any arguments in support of a trump lead. You might like leading it, but you are just playing against the odds. Perhaps a computer simulation will convince you :-) Anyway, you are free to ignore any advice :-)

Comment: btw, no one claimed _all_ trump leads are bad (just that it is bad in this specific situation) and I am pretty sure 5A is missing some vital piece of information (like maybe dummy giving preference to declarer's second suit), as that is bad advice as written. I tried to see if I can find the names of any well known experts there, but it is lacking. So I am afraid, as you say, they seem to be a bunch of self-appointed experts. I would like to point out though, from what little I have seen in that site, most of the advice seems pretty reasonable.